# I want to understand that kind of command [join]

Tags: tcl

I'm trying to learn TCL and one of my task are write a procedure that will works with that kind of code.

```
1. [join [funct [lindex $data$i]] { - }] - i dont understand that at all but...
2. [join [funct] { - }] - ... i understand this in 100%, and know what happend here
```

2. It's join list from procedure "funct" and create one string using "-" between words.
   But 1. it's some kind of magic for me. I need some special return in procedure to work with 1? Because now i just use:

```
return $data
```

Need some help ;)

Comment: It would certainly be helpful if you could show us the `proc funct` definition.

Answer (score 0):

It's mostly a matter of composition. `[funct [lindex $data $i]]` produces a list; it might look like a string, but it's a list. How do we know that? It's being fed into `join`'s first argument, and that's defined to accept a list. For the sake of argument, let's make that list be something fairly simple:

```
a {b c} d
```

Now let's do the inner `[join … { - }]`. This takes all the elements of the list and produces a string of those elements with `-` (umm, the spaces don't show real well) as a separator. On our example string, that gives:

```
a - b c - d
```

As there were three elements, there are two separators in the result. But now we're going to do `join … { - }` again round this (I'm assuming that's what you were asking). That means we reinterpret the string we've just got as a list (this is valid, if not always the most efficient approach). Note here that `-` is a perfectly fine ordinary list element literal.

```
a - - - b - c - - - d
```

It'd be clearer if we used a different character in the outer `join`. Here it is with `|` instead.

```
a | - | b | c | - | d
```

Or we could use a joiner string without spaces in. With `,` we'd get:

```
a,-,b,c,-,d
```

In general, Tcl commands do what they do immediately with no attempt to peer into the wider context of anything. Any complicated compound of commands can be decomposed into smaller pieces with helper variables and things will be semantically equivalent.

Thus, we can change `[join [join [funct [lindex $data $i]] { - }] { - }]` into:

```
set item [lindex $data $i]
set theList [funct $item]
set join1 [join $theList { - }]
set join2 [join $join1 { - }]
```

Doing this can sometimes make things much clearer!

Comment: Thanks! Now i get it. It was function with argument :D I forget about it.